# How to setup .htaccess for php site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen lots of single examples for how to setup .htaccess for single php urls for instance:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ phppage.php?p=$1 [L]
```

My basic understanding is that this will convert `phppage.php?[something]` to a more pretty looking `/phppage/`

If I have an entire site generated from a static site generator that is basically php files. How can I set rules for the entire site, or do I have to manually set rules for each directory? Help appreciated as this is mind boggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(\d+)/?$ /$1.php?p=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yep htaccess is enabled, i tested some URLs, for instance mydomain.co.uk/blog/story-1.php and there are no other rules

Comment: That is not the URL you are supposed to test since we are hiding `.php` extension. You need to enter: `mydomain.co.uk/blog/story-1` in browser (assuming `/blog/` doesn't have a .htaccess inside)

Comment: Yes sorry, I didnt write that correctly. I'm trying /story-1 but without the php extension it just says 'not found'

Comment: Correct the none php version doesnt work but the .php version does. Can't work out what I could be doing wrong :S

Comment: Hi there, sorry for slow reply. If you look at: http://getdoidgeupamountain.co.uk/blog/ you can see I've got it working for index and the blog story itself, but there is a page called blog.php which its not going to and instead going to the folder /blog/

Comment: Ok if `/blog/` is a directory and its a file also `/blog.php` then you need to remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` from both rules. (see updated one)

Comment: Your amazing, thank you so much. Sorry for the hassle but works now. Thanks again!